# How can i automate 'Settings' app in real iOS devices?

Tags: ios, ui-automation, appium, ios-ui-automation, monkeytalk

I tried with Appium, UI Automation and Monkey Talk to automate native app automation for real iOS device. Mentioned tools are not supporting real iOS native app automation.

Is there a (freeware) tool that automates native apps of real iOS devices?

Comment: Can you provide a use case for this?  UIAutomation (and the wrappers for UIAutomation that you listed) would allow you to control your own app, but Apple's sandboxing would prevent you from controlling a system app.

Comment: Disregard previous comment, I was thinking of the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in your Terminal:

`instruments -v -w YOUR_DEVICE_ID -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/Applications/Preferences.app -e UIASCRIPT /Users/mytests/Documents/xCode/Shell-Script/YourTestScript-App.js`

The above command is a 1 liner.
But you need to write your own test script called **YourTestScript-App.js**

Comment: That won't work on a device. You're specifying the device ID and then giving it the path of the *Preference* app on your simulator.

Comment: yes I have and it didn't work for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Ricardo: It works for me. Can you tell me what the error message is or what kind of problem you have?

Comment: Here's the error:  "Target failed to run: Permission to debug com.apple.Preferences was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer)."

Comment: @Ricardo: Have you started Xcode? Can you connect the phone with Xcode? Do you have a iOS developer account? I am wonder if that is the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82653/discussion-between-ricardo-b-and-empario).

Comment: @MagnusO. Nope. It only works on the simulator but not on a real device. Did you get it working?

Comment: @RicardoB. Sorry no. Seems like it is not possible.