# iOS uiautomator application names

Tags: ios, xcode6, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to launch and test iOS app's with Xcode instruments.
But I do not have every app name for the testing.

For example, I know:

- **SETTINGS == Preferences.app**
- **SAFARI == MobileSafari.app**

What is app the name for **Calendar**, **Mail**, **Photos**, **Messages**, **Camera**, ...?

Comment: Are you actually running UIAutomation tests against these system apps?

Comment: Interesting.  Is this done as part of testing your own app? What sort of things are you able to learn by testing the system apps?

Comment: @Ian: I am not testing in a particular App rather on the phone behavior for specific scenarios, e.g. iCloud log in/out, WiFi set up , GSM in 3G/4G.

Comment: So you run these (one app at a time) against the phone?  Sorry to ask so many questions, but it's my understanding that automation ends when the frontmost app changes.

Comment: @Ian: Yes, you are right. One App at a time but I have a script for each of these Apps, so I can run many Apps in 1 automation run. Please vote if this helped you. Thanks.

Comment: @Ian: An addition to the answer above, please review this link for more information how to run these Apps in a script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465731/how-can-i-automate-settings-app-in-real-ios-devices/30202480#30202480

Comment: No worries, I'm familiar with that part of automation.  I actually wrote [an iOS app testing framework](https://github.com/paypal/Illuminator), but I'm always looking for more ways to make it more powerful.

Comment: @Ian: I appreciate the link, it looks very helpful. I will definitely take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @Empario I'm still puzzled at how you can automate the native apps on a "real" device. I keep getting a permission denied error because I don't have the source code of the "Preference.app" or any other native apps on the device. Do you have a jailbroken device? Does it only work on earlier iOS versions?

Comment: @Ricardo: My phone is not jailbroken and I have not tried an earlier iOS version. This permission issue might be related to your account but I am not really sure since I do not know your set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the answer and hopefully it helps others as well:

- **Calendar == MobileCal.app**
- **Mail == MobileMail.app**
- **Photos == MobileSlideShow.app**
- **Messages == MobileSMS.app**
- **Camera == Camera.app**

Comment: I cannot find Mail and Messages from the simulator folder (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/Applications, and I am using XCode 7). Are you able to find those two apps? Could you provide more details on where you get those app? Many thanks!

Comment: @zyzyis: You path is right but I am not sure why you are not able to see Mail and Messages. Which *.app files do you see in that directory?

Comment: I can see lots of other apps, e.g. Preferences.app, MobileCal.app, Maps.app, somehow there is no MobileMail.app, could you let me know which version of XCode and Simulator you are using? Thanks.